# jquery combine ready and click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have the same piece of code that runs for both Ready and Click events, but when I try to combine them it doesn't work

```
$("input[name='reimburse']").on("ready click", function() {
    //some code
});
```

I think it has to do it the Ready function because even this doesn't work

```
$("input[name='reimburse']").on("ready", function() {
    //some code
});
```

Instead I have to do this for Ready functionality

```
$("input[name='reimburse']").ready(function() {
    //some code
});
```

Other than creating another JS function and calling that method from 2 different declared events, how can I achieve my initial code?  Why doesn't calling `on("ready")` work?

EDIT:
Its been brought to my attention that `ready` event is not applicable for individual DOM's and that `load` should be used instead.  I have tried this but still doesn't work.  Only the `click` event works.  I have also tried replacing `on` with `bind` and same thing happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ready` event applies to the document, not to individual DOM elements.  So, there is no specific `ready` event that applies to the `"input[name='reimburse']"` DOM elements.

If what you're trying to do is to have the same function fire both when the page is first loaded and when a specific click event is fired, then you can put your common event handling code into a named function and then refer to that function from two separate event handlers:

```
function myHandler(e) {
    // code here
}

$(document).ready(myHandler);
$("input[name='reimburse']").on("click", myHandler);
```

Though, the last line of code above will only work IF those DOM elements are already loaded.  As such, you may need to put that line of code inside a `.ready()` handler (depending upon where the code is being run from).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='reimburse']").on("click", myHandler);
    myHandler();
});
```

Here's another related answer: [jQuery.ready() equivalent event listener on elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355791/jquery-ready-equivalent-event-listener-on-elements/19355923#19355923)

> Why doesn't calling on("ready") work?

Because jQuery decided not to support that structure.  jQuery used to support `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, but as of jQuery v1.8, that support has been deprecated (e.g. you shouldn't use it because it will be removed).  Per the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), these three forms can be used for `.ready()`.

```
$( document ).ready( handler )
$().ready( handler )             // works, but not recommended
$( handler )
```

---

If it is bothering you to have to both specify an event handler and call your function at initiatialization time, then you could create your own plug-in that would do that for you:

```
 $.fn.initOn = function(events, handler) {
     this.on(events, handler);
     handler();
 }
```

Then, instead of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='reimburse']").on("click", myHandler);
    myHandler();
});
```

You could just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='reimburse']").initOn("click", myHandler);
});
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing it this way because I have multiple DOM's on this page that require this type of behavior.  So this would mean me having to create a bunch of `myHandler()` functions and explicitly calling them each twice as you have shown in your example.  If that is the only choice then so be it, but it just looks ugly

Comment: @RaymondHolguin - what do you mean "multiple DOMs"?  There's only one DOM per document (that contains multiple objects) so I think you'll have to explain more about your actual problem before we can help you best.

Comment: @RaymondHolguin - see the custom option I added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can just imitate the click on ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[name='reimburse']").click(function() {
        //some code
    });

    $("input[name='reimburse']").click();
});
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid do that as it seems sloppy.  Also this page has many similar events and doesn't seem good to manually trigger a bunch of click events if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$("input[name='reimburse']").bind("ready click", function() {
    //some code
});
```

According to the documentation

> Multiple event types can be bound at once by including each one
>   separated by a space

Note, `ready` is valid for `document` and shouldn't be used for elements. To get similar functionality, use `load`

```
$("input[name='reimburse']").bind("load click", function() {
    //some code
});
```

Comment: As far as I know, the problem with "bind" is that it doesn't bind the event to dynamically added DOM elements, which is ".on" 's advantage.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either.  The click works, but now the `ready` portion

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery docs here: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to .on( "ready" ) the bound handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

While you shouldn't be using deprecated methods whenever possible, I'm curious, where are you setting your event listeners?

Comment: I have tried inside the `document.ready` method as well as outside of it.  same result.