# How to get to know when large table data rendering is finished (not full page load or not ajax complete) totally static large data

Tags: javascript, html

How to get to know when large table data rendering is finished (not full page load or not ajax complete) totally static large data

Is there any browser event like onload  or something which fired for each sub element of a DOM

Comment: Just load data on scroll ! 
For that use js plugin

Comment: can you share the code, which you have tried?

Comment: May I ask why do you need that? Whether the table takes considerable time or not, waiting for the whole document would be enough, and the best approach IMO.

Comment: We have heavy JSON static data. So table takes around 4 second to render.

Comment: @Sebastianb We have heavy static JSON data. So table takes around 4 second to render. We need to run some code after full table render.   We are more interested to get some event notifier about full rendering of table instead of full page load event (onload) (as table need to render many time based on user input). We dont need generic approach like lazy loading, render only required data,

Comment: check this answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355791/jquery-ready-equivalent-event-listener-on-elements
Maybe an inline script in the table that calls a function in your main js file?

Comment: @Sebastianb thanks ....wl try this approache