# disable textbox if equal to set value

Tags: jquery, html

How will i disable textbox2 if the textbox 1 is equal to `true`. it's not inputted value its set value.

```js
$('#valuetags').ready(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
    $('#quantitytotransfer').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#quantitytotransfer').prop('disabled', false);
  }
)};
```

```html
<input name="valuetags" type="text" value="true" class="form-control" id="valuetags"> 

<input type="number"  required class="form-control" name="quantitytotransfer" id="quantitytotransfer" maxlength="11">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ready` for element. Only for the document.

```js
$(function(){
  if ($('#valuetags').val() == 'true') {
    $('#quantitytotransfer').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#quantitytotransfer').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<input name="valuetags" type="text" value="true" class="form-control" id="valuetags"> 

<input type="number"  required class="form-control" name="quantitytotransfer" id="quantitytotransfer" maxlength="11">
```

Here is a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355923/863110) about this issue.

**By the way** You can short your code by pass the condition as the variable to `prop` function:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#quantitytotransfer').prop('disabled', $('#valuetags').val() == 'true');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<input name="valuetags" type="text" value="true" class="form-control" id="valuetags"> 

<input type="number"  required class="form-control" name="quantitytotransfer" id="quantitytotransfer" maxlength="11">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you input text to `valuetags` it's value attribute is overwritten with the user's input value, i.e. `value="true"` is no longer set.

Try adding a different attribute in the html such as `data-value="true"` then

```
if ($(this).data("value") == 'true'){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function activer(){
          if ($('#valuetags').val() == 'true') {
            $('#quantitytotransfer').prop('disabled', true);
          } else {
            $('#quantitytotransfer').prop('disabled', false);
            ;
          }
        }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            activer();
            $('#valuetags').on('change', function() {
              activer();
            });
        });
```